# C# Int64 Parsing - Throwing errors?

Tags: c#

I took a challenge to create a basic console based calculator. I've got a function that's supposed to return a factorial of a number, although I've used `Int32.Parse`. If I try to display a factorial of any number larger than 19, it overflows. I have attempted to switch to `Int64.Parse`, `Convert.ToInt64`, which didn't work. Later I noticed `long` is the 64-bit integer type. I replaced the integer with long and tried `Int64.Parse`, and `Convert.ToInt64`. None of these work. I have even made an exception for numbers larger than 19, it says that it will probably get errors. Here's my basic code:

```
string factInput;
int userInput; //Or: long userInput; (Both throw errors)

Console.WriteLine("What number do you want to display the factorial of? Please type in the number when prompted.");
Console.WriteLine("Please type in number:");

factInput = Console.ReadLine();
userInput = Int64.Parse(factInput);

if (userInput >= 20)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found error - Integer bound to 32-bit integer overflow limit. Continuing operation, expecting errors.");
}

Console.WriteLine("Calculation completed. Result:");
Console.WriteLine(Fact(userInput));
userInput = 0;
factInput = "nul";
```

Comment: What does `Fact` take as a parameter? Can you post the implementation?

Comment: Note you are calculating `Fact(userInput)` even when `userInput >= 20`. I mean, you need an `else` branch.

Comment: What errors exactly? At what line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum value of an `int` / `Int32` is **2,147,483,647** an that of a `long` / `Int64` is **9,223,372,036,854,775,807** while the factorial of *21* for example is **51,090,942,171,709,440,000**. This is way bigger than that maximum value!

You should make use of the `BigInteger` class. This class resides in the `System.Numerics` namespace.

Add a reference to your project to the `System.Numerics` assembly and add following line to the `using` part of your code:

```
using System.Numerics;
```

Then your `Fact` method could look like this:

```
public static BigInteger Fact(long input)
{
    var result = new BigInteger(input);
    while (--input > 0)
    {
        result *= input;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Note:** this is absolutely not the most optimal/performant way of calculating the factorial of a number. You can search Google for methods to calculate it more efficiently.

The use of the method would then be:

```
Console.WriteLine(Fact(userInput));
```

Comment: Actually, I've got a small problem. If I add System.Numerics... just another error :/ This is it: The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
:( Please help!

Comment: @ImNotCrazy Did you follow this step: `Add a reference to your project to the System.Numerics assembly`?

Comment: Hmm,  no... But that really doesn't ring a bell, I don't really know how to do that :/

Comment: In your project, right-click on `References` and select `Add reference...`. Here you can look for the `System.Numerics` assembly, select it and click `OK`.